# Sell WooCommerce Products from Other Sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 WooCommerce storefronts on 2 separate sites.  They're just typical Woo setups.

I want to create a 3rd site that will sell the products of both of my current stores, is this possible?

Currently, one store focuses on food, while the other store focuses on alcohol.  I would like the new site to offer the products of both the food store and the alcohol store.

How I would like it to function:
1) If I add a product to one of the 2 stores, it will also appear on the 3rd site
2) If a user makes a purchase on the new site, it will process through the current sites (the food store and alcohol store).  So, if someone buys both food and alcohol, then it would need to create 1 order on the food store, and 1 order on the alcohol store

Answer (score 0):

Create API that gets products from one and from other woocommerce site, then use it on 3rd site and json_decode it and you got products from both side